# Unable to highlight/select textField after filling it with a value using pdf-lib

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

I want to dynamically update fields inside some pdf files and use them. For the sake of user experience, I want the fields to be able to be highlighted so it's easier to copy/paste so I don't have to input the values later manually... but I have been unsuccessful in finding a solution.

Here's my code that fills out the textFields using pdf-lib:

```
const pdf = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(filedata);
const form = pdf.getForm();

var textField = form.getTextField(TEXTFIELD_NAME);

textField.setMaxLength(20);

textField.setText("Some value");

textField.enableReadOnly();
const pdfToBytes = await pdf.save();
```

And then I create a file using "pdfToBytes", but when opening the PDF using any PDF viewer, I'm unable to highlight/select the value inside the textField.

I have tried `textField.disableReadonly`, but I actually want the field to be read only, and it doesn't really work in all PDF viewers when doing so anyways.

Comment: The *ReadOnly* form field flag is specified as *If set, the user may not change the value of the field. **Any associated widget annotations will not interact with the user; that is, they will not respond to mouse clicks or change their appearance in response to mouse motions.** This flag is useful for fields whose values are computed or imported from a database.* Thus, the observed behavior is exactly the expected behavior.

Comment: @mkl I know that this is the expected behaviour, which allows the user to highlight the text **because** they can edit it, but I want to be able to highlight the text without allowing the user to change the value of the textField.

Comment: Well, there is an annotation flag that might help, *LockedContents* (*If set, do not allow the contents of the annotation to be modified by the user. This flag does not restrict deletion of the annotation or changes to other annotation properties, such as position and size.*). If that doesn't work, the next best option would be flattening the form...

Comment: @mkl Thanks a lot, I will give that a shot and post an answer to my own question if it worked.